# Convert site from wordpress to Plone 4

Tags: wordpress, plone

I have been asked to convert an entire site that is currently using wordpress to Plone 4.1. I have no experience using Plone and I was wondering if anyone has attempted this before? I had a look and can't find much information about converting to Plone and I was wondering if anyone had come across some good advice? This does seem like a rather big task...

Thanks,
Fraser

Comment: It would be nice if you could clarify the scope of the kinds of content you need to import (posts, pages, media files, comments, etc) -- what are your priorities.  It is hard to judge any answer without knowing this.  For example, importing from wordpress RSS is usually a minimalistic approach, but sometimes appropriate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, someone already performed that specific migration:

http://davisagli.com/blog/notes-on-migrating-this-blog-from-wordpress-to-plone

As the author says, another approach to this task it's :

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.transmogrifier

Answer (score 2):

Adam Terry will be giving a [talk on the easy way of converting sites](http://2011ploneconference.sched.org/event/6d6cb041191cc048f5a6736a18974fe2) like this in 2 days at the Plone Conference in San Francisco. I would recommend attending (for many reasons, not just that talk).
Failing that, the short summary of the talk is two tools.

Diazo (or now called [plone.app.theming](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.theming)) - Makes replicating an existing theme much easier.

and

[Funnelweb](http://plone.org/products/funnelweb) (which does all the collective.transmogrifier stuff for you) - Makes coverting all the content easier.

Note: this is an approach for any site, not just wordpress. It relies on webcrawling a site. An approach which directly reads the database, if you have access, might be easier and cleaner.

Comment: Just to note that Diazo (http://diazo.org) is the engine used by plone.app.theming. They used to be called XDV and collective.xdv.

Answer (score -1):

This is a massive task, not difficult, but time consuming. Its not really a question that can be answered on stackoverflow, but i can point you in the right direction of some decent doco.

Here is a good place to start - http://noenieto.com/blog/theming-plone-4

Beware, Plones theming engine is very different to anything you will have experienced before. If i was you I would firstly create a static template of your theme and build on that. I have been developing plone skins for 5+ years now, and i always start with a static theme.

Many plone developers are using [Diazo](http://diazo.org/) / [Deliverance](http://www.coactivate.org/projects/deliverance/project-home) to develop plone themes, maybe take a look at those too...

Good luck, im afraid you're going to need it!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it sounds like it's going to take MUCH more than a couple of days (as I was told).